# What is the best way to save token (JWT) in cakephp 4?

Tags: cakephp, jwt, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-4.x

I have a project and I made the backend using nodejs.
I made a user registration module and the authentication generates a token!
This token will need to be used in other requests where the user must be logged in.

**What is the best way to store this token on the frontend using cakephp 4?**

Is there any component? Is it safe to store this token using the session?

I would appreciate it if someone could help analyze this case.

This is my authentication method:

```
public function login()
    {
        $http = new Client();
        
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $response = $http->post(
                'http://localhost:8889/api/auth/login',
                [
                    'email' => $this->request->getData("username"),
                    'password' => $this->request->getData("password"),
                ]
            );

            if ($response->getStatusCode() == 401) {
                return $this->redirect($this->referer());
            }

            if ($response->isOk()) {
                $json = $response->getJSON();
                    return $this->redirect(['action' => 'home', 'controller' => 'Pages']);
            }
        }
    }
```

Return 200 contains an accessToken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to store the token is with an HttpOnly Cookie.

> According to the Microsoft Developer Network, HttpOnly is an
> additional flag included in a Set-Cookie HTTP response header. Using
> the HttpOnly flag when generating a cookie helps mitigate the risk of
> client-side script accessing the protected cookie (if the browser
> supports it).

If you store it in a LocalStorage/SessionStorage then it can be easily grabbed by an XSS attack (from Javascript/Client side)

The CakePHP 4 way to do it is like this:

https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/controllers/request-response.html#creating-cookies

```
$cookie = new Cookie(
    'jwt_token', // name
    'token', // value
    new DateTime('+1 hour'), // expiration time
    '/', // path
    'example.com', // domain
    true, // secure only?
    true // http only -> this is what you need
);
```